# Border to fit reference \cite{book}

Tags: biblatex, fbox

How can I put or resize a `fbox` to fit a reference `\cite{author}` like this?

[image]

```
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\begin{document} 
\newcommand{\cfbox}[2]{%
\colorlet{currentcolor}{.}%
{\color{#1}%
\fbox{\color{currentcolor}#2}}%
}
\hypersetup{backref=true,       
pagebackref=true,               
hyperindex=true,                
colorlinks=true,                
breaklinks=true,                
urlcolor= black,                
linkcolor= blue,                
bookmarks=true,                 
bookmarksopen=false,
filecolor=black,
citecolor=black,
linkbordercolor=blue
}
\end{document}
citecolor green citation links (bibliography) \cfbox{green}{\cite{bib00}}
```

Output: citecolor green citation links (bibliography)  [image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Since you employ the `hyperref` package, you might as well let it do the job of drawing frame lines around numeric-style citation call-outs.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[pdfborder={0 0 0.4}]{hyperref} % '0.4': width of frame line, in pts

\begin{document}
\cite{aaa}

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem{aaa} AAA
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I tried your solution but it doesn't work. Since I am a beginner on latex. I used this template https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl  but its problem is there are missing packages.

Comment: @кестеняво - Sorry, but remarks such as "it doesn't work" are not actionable. If my proposed solution doesn't work for you, it must be because your document employs a different setup. Sadly, but maybe not surprisingly, my mind-reading  and divination skills are just rubbish, and the chances that I'll successfully guess on my own what your document setup looks like are nil. Unless you tell us fairly specifically what "it doesn't work" entails -- error messages? warning messages? something else? -- chances that anybody will be able to come up with a diagnosis, let alone a cure, are rather poor.

Comment: I totally agree with you. except that I did not receive an error message and during the execution nothing changes for the references.  Also I agree that this Template  https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/template-for-a-masters-slash-doctoral-thesis/mkzrzktcbzfl uses a different configuration.